# Problem with importing matplotlib in python

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, jupyter-lab, miniconda

I have matplotlib installed. I double checked it if its there using **conda list** and **pip list** commands.
However, when I am importing it, it says the error **'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib''**

Now, I typically understand what it this error means and as mentioned, I have it installed. But the issue persist.

What can be my starting point to sort this issue?

[image]

Comment: This seems to a be problem in the way path is defined for the library. Perhaps this link may help : https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-fix-modulenotfounderror-and-importerror-248ce5b69b1c

Comment: Can you run `pip show matplotlib` and tell if you are getting matplotlib versio?

Comment: I had the same problem, and solved it by updating matplotlib. Not sure why it worked, though.

Comment: Yes @Red Devi and Imsteffan, I ran pip show matplotlib and I am getting the version 3.6.0. I later downgraded to an older version, 3.5.2 and ran into same issue, then update again and ran into the same issue.

Comment: Are you sure, you installed environment and the running one are same?

Comment: @Red Devil. Yes I am sure of this. I made a virtual environment and then installed all packages there before running. All other packages are running fine in the same virtual environment.

Comment: Can you try installing the package globally?